# How to extract two columns from a matrix in a sequence of 6 columns in matlab

Tags: matlab

Basically I have a <96x659 double> matrix and I want to extract 1st and 2nd column , then 8th and 9th, then 15th and 16th column and so on..
So I want each 2 columns in a step of 6 . I hope I was clear enough. I'm newbie in matlab .
Thanks in advance!

Comment: something this basic is better answered by yourself, by reading the documentation or doing a little bit of searching.

Comment: @zeffii Okay, this isn't the most difficult of questions, but it is by no means straightforward for a complete newbie, which the OP admitted to being. Remember, for many people, Matlab is their first attempt at programming in any language. However, I would mention to the OP that it is customary to provide some evidence in the question that you've tried but failed to solve the problem yourself. Even some code that doesn't work is better than no code at all! :-)

Comment: @ColinTBowers Sure, I appreciate that the random person on the street has a small likelihood of being able to answer the question. But surely we are robbing this person of a much more vital learning experience by directly answering the question. Immediate gratification and all that. Where will the OP go to find the answers to his other questions?

Comment: @zeffii I would certainly agree that it can be a grey area. But in this particular case, I'd choose carrot over stick for two reasons: 1) The OP took the time to pick a real user-name which IMHO means there is some chance of OP becoming a contributing member to the community given some encouragement, and 2) many newbies will conclude on their own that the "right" solution to this problem is with a loop, and it could be months before they realize their mistake. But I certainly agree the question should have contained evidence of an attempt at a solution.

Comment: @ColinTBowers We could go back and forth on this for a while, but our points have been stated by others many times over. This kind of question deserves to be intercepted before posting, by questions like 'this is your first question about (topic-language), have you read (topic-language) docs/help/tutorials? - if yes show some code you tried, even if it doesn't work - if no, here are some links and this is how easy it is to add code to your post'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you really need to do is construct the list of columns you want:

```
columns = [1:7:size(matrix,2)+1,  2:7:size(matrix,2)+1];
submat = matrix(:, columns);
```

Keep in mind this will not necessarily return the columns in the order you want. If you want the columns in ascending order, you could substitute

```
submat = matrix(:, sort(columns));
```

Answer (score 0):

[Matlab Summary and Tutorial](http://www.math.ufl.edu/help/matlab-tutorial/matlab-tutorial.html)

This is a pretty decent introduction, if the Matlab documentation itself appears to be a little dense. Go through the examples, try them out.